# Array index in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

```
$scope.ptArray={m1 : $scope.somevalue1, 
                m2 : $scope.somevalue2, 
                m3 : $scope.somevalue3};
$scope.errMsg={m1 : 'msg1',
                 m2 : 'msg2', 
                 m3 : 'msg3'};
if($scope.ptArray.this==""){
            alert($scope.errMsg.this);
            }
```

'this' doesn't work here. If I use m1, m2 or m3 instead of 'this' it will work, but only for that variable. What to use in the place of this

Comment: What do you expect "this" to be? It's not magic.

Comment: I was just trying to tell what i wanted sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Get all the keys that have an empty `String` as a value:

```
var empty = [];
Object.keys($scope.ptArray).forEach((k) => {if(ptArray[k] == ""){empty.push(k);}});
```

Create an alert with the messages for all those keys:

```
var msg = "";
empty.forEach((k) => {msg+=$scope.errMsg[k]+"\n"});
if(msg.length > 0){
    alert(msg);
}
```

or do all that at once in a single loop:

```
var msg = "":
Object.keys($scope.ptArray).forEach((k) => 
      {
        if(ptArray[k] == ""){
            msg += $scope.errMsg[k]+"\n";
        }
      });
if(msg.length > 0){
    alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to the dict you can use...

```
if($scope.ptArray[str]==""){
     alert($scope.errMsg[str]);
}
```

Where `str` is a String with value `'m1'`, `'m2'` or `'m3'`.
But Use an array can be a better option:

```
  if($scope.ptArray[index]==""){
     alert($scope.errMsg[index]);
}
```

where index is an integer value.

I don't know what you want to do with `this`.

Comment: $scope.errMsg[index] returns [object Object] doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
$scope.ptArray={m1 : $scope.somevalue1, 
            m2 : $scope.somevalue2, 
            m3 : $scope.somevalue3};
$scope.errMsg={m1 : 'msg1',
             m2 : 'msg2', 
             m3 : 'msg3'};

Object.keys($scope.ptArray).forEach(function(node){
           if($scope.ptArray[node]==""){
                console.log($scope.errMsg[node]);
           }
     });
```